# How to build form with multiple components in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to build Reactive-Form spanning multiple components, something like this

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitted()">
   <app-names></app-names>
   <app-address></app-address>
   <app-phones></app-phones>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I try to submit, I get empty object.

[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nunkzr)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make the following changes

1.Use only one `FormGroup` instead of creating the new `FormGroup` for each component.

2.You have `@Input` for `FormGroup` however you are not passing as input.

3.Remove `FormBuilder` from the child component.

### app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitted()">
    <app-names [myForm]="myForm"></app-names>
    <app-address [myForm]="myForm"></app-address>
    <app-phones [myForm]="myForm"></app-phones>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### address.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup,FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css']
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.addControl("homeAddress" , new FormControl());
    this.myForm.addControl("officeAddress" , new FormControl());
  }

}
```

Make the similar changes for other components.

Answer (score 10):

There's another option to do it without using @Input

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormControl,
    ControlContainer,
    FormGroupDirective
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
     }
  ]
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const myForm = this.parent.form;
    myForm.addControl("homeAddress", new FormControl());
    myForm.addControl("officeAddress", new FormControl());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million mate, I've never seen this way of doing this and I find it so simple and clean!